# snowflake sql: sum for each day between two dates

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I hope someone can help. Suppose I have this table

| id | actual_date | target_date | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-01 | 3 |
| 4 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| 5 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-03 | 2 |

what i would like to calculate is the qty that has to be processed on each date.

E.g. on the target date 2022-01-01 the quota qty is 6 (2+1+3).

On the 2.1.2022 i would also have to add the qtys that havent been processed on the day before, which means id 2 because the actual date is 2022-01-02 (so after the target date) and id 3. The quota qty for the 2022-01-02 is then 1+3+1.

And for the  2022-01-03 is 6 = 2+1+3, because id 3 has an actual date on 2022-01-02 (it wasnt processed neither on 01-01 nor on 01-02 and id 4 wasnt processed on 01-02.

Here's what the desired output would look like:

| target_date | qty_qouta |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 6 |
| 2022-01-02 | 4 |
| 2022-01-03 | 6 |

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hopefully this gets you started ... recommend testing heaps more edge cases, the business rules don't quite feel right to me -> as you don't seem to show when actual>target. But hope this helps.

```
WITH CTE AS( SELECT 1 ID, '2022-01-01'::DATE ACTUAL_DATE,'2022-01-01'::DATE TARGET_DATE, 2 QTY
UNION ALL SELECT 2 ID, '2022-01-02'::DATE ACTUAL_DATE,'2022-01-01'::DATE TARGET_DATE, 1 QTY
UNION ALL SELECT 3 ID, '2022-01-03'::DATE ACTUAL_DATE,'2022-01-01'::DATE TARGET_DATE, 3 QTY
UNION ALL SELECT 4 ID, '2022-01-03'::DATE ACTUAL_DATE,'2022-01-02'::DATE TARGET_DATE, 1 QTY
UNION ALL SELECT 5 ID, '2022-01-03'::DATE ACTUAL_DATE,'2022-01-03'::DATE TARGET_DATE, 2 QTY
)
,CTE2 AS(SELECT 
     ACTUAL_DATE D
 ,   SUM(QTY) ACTUAL_QTY
  FROM CTE GROUP BY 1)
,CTE3 AS(SELECT 
     TARGET_DATE D
 ,   SUM(QTY) TARGET_QTY
  FROM CTE GROUP BY 1)
  SELECT 
     D DATE
    ,ACTUAL_QTY
    ,TARGET_QTY
    ,TARGET_QTY-ACTUAL_QTY DELTA
    ,ZEROIFNULL(LAG(DELTA)OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY D))GHOST
    ,GREATEST(TARGET_QTY,DELTA+GHOST,ACTUAL_QTY)VOLIA
   FROM 
        CTE2 FULL OUTER JOIN CTE3 USING(D);
```